# Advance line number in ruby loop containing .each_line

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration

This might be a more general programming question, but I'm wondering what the best practice for ruby is in solving this problem. I want to parse a file with some structure like this:

```
toplevel blah blah 0
  attr0: foo
  attr1: bar
  nextlevel something 0
    child0: baz
    child1: boz
      var1: blah    
  nextlevel something 1
    child0: faz
      abc: yes
    child1: foz
```

I've considered using split and parsing out the chunks or possibly iterating over the file with `.each_line` and then somehow (I don't know how) do a nested iteration

the nested line, I imagine, would look something like this:

```
input.each_line do |line|
  #parse attributes 
  if line =~ /nextlevel:\s+(\d)/ then
     #now advance the line count somehow and continue parsing in here
  end
```

P.S. sorry if the names are a little messy in the example, but I was trying to come up with a simplified MWE.

Comment: Isn't "advance line count" just `line_count += 1` or ..? ;-)

Comment: Anyway, I would *not* use `each_line` for this, but rather pass the (open) File to *recursive functions* and have each consume the line(s) as required. It looks like the indent (or lack thereof) determines the base and recursive cases ..

Comment: Also, it looks like it could be fiddled into (or written in) [YAML](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/YAML.html) or another markup format (based on preference?) and *then* consumed .. ? It is easiest to use existing tooling and it also reduces the introduction of "new one-off formats".

Comment: Unfortunately, it is output from proprietary code, so I'm stuck with the format. Re: recursive parsing - are there any solid examples of dealing with this style format in ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sort structure you're trying to extract?

```
def parse(inp, level)
    until inp.eof?
        line = inp.gets
        if line =~ /nextlevel:\s+(\d)/
            parse(inp, $1.to_i)
        else
            puts "got line: '#{line.strip}' at level #{level}"
        end
    end
end

irb(main):070:0> parse(input, -1)
got line: 'toplevel: 0' at level -1
got line: 'attr0: foo' at level -1
got line: 'attr1: bar' at level -1
got line: 'child0: baz' at level 0
got line: 'child1: boz' at level 0
got line: 'child0: faz' at level 1
got line: 'child1: foz' at level 1
=> nil
```

This uses a recursive method to keep track of the depth using the stack, but it would be equally simple to do so using a variable and an iterative approach.

Comment: That definitely helps, unfortunately the format is more arbitrary. However, I might be able to take what you've got and count whitespace instead or something.  I wish I could just copy+paste the actual output, but it wouldn't be allowed

Comment: I'd like to help you more, but I'm still not clear on what structure you're trying to extract from your file. If you could perhaps give an example of what you would like your program's output to be, I might be able to help you outline how your ruby needs to look.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the trouble I'm having sharing the details. Basically, I'd like to eventually build a hash or some other type of structure out of this data to represent the hierarchy shown in the sample input data. In the output I'm dealing with, there is somewhat of a predefined notion of what to expect at each level - so I could create a separate object for each level and populate them appropriately, counting whitespace to determine the level.

Answer (score 1):

that looks like YAML format  ... ruby has a module to parse that for you http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/YAML.html

Comment: It's not strict YAML, I've revised my MWE to edit it to be closer to the output I'm dealing with